# Dynamic SubSelects in SQL Select Statement

Tags: sql, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I am querying a table for some basic information, file number, case type, status, etc.  In addition I need a column for every single one of 138 case status types that will display the date the case had that status.  Here is a sample:

```
SELECT  FileNum,
        CaseType,
        CurrentCaseStatus,
        (SELECT TOP 1 EventDt FROM caseStatusHistory WHERE CaseID = c.caseID AND CaseStatus = 'CS001' ORDER BY EventDt DESC) AS [Charge - Phone],
        (SELECT TOP 1 EventDt FROM caseStatusHistory WHERE CaseID = c.caseID AND CaseStatus = 'CS002' ORDER BY EventDt DESC) AS [Charge - Written],
        -- 136 more just like the live above
FROM    Case c
```

I can query another table for all the case status types:

```
SELECT Code, Description
FROM caseStatus
WHERE Code BETWEEN 'CS001' AND 'CS138'
ORDER BY Code
```

How can I dynamically create each of those columns instead of having to manually write 138 select statements?

Comment: Are the charge texts unique for each line? as [Charge - Phone] etc

Comment: Does description same as column name charge -phone etc, then we can just use group by , non need for CASE at all

Comment: Yes, the texts are unique.

Answer (score 0):

That's going to be terribly slow -- 138 correlated subqueries.  I think you can achieve the same result with an `OUTER JOIN` and a `GROUP BY` with MAX and `CASE`:

```
Select c.filenum,
       c.casetype,
       c.currentcasestatus,
       max(case when csh.CaseStatus = 'CS001' then EventDt end) as [Charge - Phone],
       max(case when csh.CaseStatus = 'CS002' then EventDt end) as [Charge - Written]
from case c
    left join casestatushistory csh on c.caseid = csh.caseid 
group by  c.filenum,
       c.casetype,
       c.currentcasestatus
```

BTW, I would suggest just writing the statement out -- it won't take that long and it will out perform a dynamic sql approach.  I'm not completely sure how you'd get your column names with dynamic sql either unless `Phone` and `Written` are in another column.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a PIVOT.  The SQL below should work -

```
--Select the pivot data into a temp table
SELECT c.caseID,
    c.FileNum, 
    c.CaseType, 
    c.CurrentCaseStatus,
    csh.EventDt,
    cs.Description
INTO #StatusDates
FROM [Case] c
LEFT JOIN caseStatusHistory csh
ON csh.caseID = c.caseID
LEFT JOIN caseStatus cs
ON cs.Code = csh.CaseStatus

--From the pivot data, get the list of field names (assumes description field is the source for the field name)
DECLARE @statusDescriptions VARCHAR(MAX)
SET @statusDescriptions = ''
SELECT @statusDescriptions = COALESCE(@statusDescriptions+'[','') + Description 
FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT Description 
    FROM #StatusDates 
    WHERE Description IS NOT NULL
) x
SET @statusDescriptions = REPLACE(@statusDescriptions, '[', '],[') + ']'
SET @statusDescriptions = SUBSTRING(@statusDescriptions, 3, LEN(@statusDescriptions))

--Create a SQL statement to pivot the data into the fields.
DECLARE @sql VARCHAR(MAX)
SET @SQL = '
    SELECT *
    FROM #StatusDates
    PIVOT(MIN(EventDt)
    FOR Description IN (' + @statusDescriptions + '))
    AS PVTTable '
PRINT @sql
EXEC(@sql)
DROP TABLE #StatusDates
```